# EDB log files accumulating on Windows 2003 DC

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, log-files

We have a domain controller that has over 4,000 edb*.log files since 11/29/10. Our other DCs have one file. The kb247715 article discusses how the edb logs work. Clearly something isn't right on the DC; however, there is nothing in the logs to indicate why the circular logging process isn't working properly.

---

From our SysAdmin that handles backups--

Did some looking into this and it actually might be an issue with the backup software and this server. Not sure yet why this server only... but from what I was reading the backups should remove the logs (like Exchange). However on this server it's not.

I ran ntbackup system state backup to a c:\backup-temp and after it was done all of the extra log files cleared up.

Can't test with brighstor right now (adjusted to just backup everything on this server) because of other backups running.

Will continue to test options.

Comment: Please check the events in Active Directory logs, this DC has our of version storage issue I Guess.